# Trouble installing APSW

Tags: 14.04, python

I am trying to install APSW on my 14.04 ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-apsw
```

But then, this is displayed on my terminal:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 234 not upgraded.
```

It says my "python apsw is already in the newest version" but I cannot use it and I keep on getting errors when trying to. Do the 234 not upgraded packages have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to update your packages:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

After that install `pip` if it's not installed:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

for python2, and for python3:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

then install `APSW` using pip:

```
sudo pip install apsw
```

or for your own user only:

```
pip install apsw --user
```